# How can I create this asymmetrical shape and also curve the shape around a 90 degree axis?

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I am trying to create this shape (A) and then once created add a curve to it, so that from the top elevation it looks like (B)

As with all the solutions presented by the gurus I am sure this is really simple however, it is alluding me at this moment in time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Asymmetrical shape and top elevation]

Answer (score 0):

Create your profile:

[image]

Position it properly on the Z axis:

[image]

Add a 90° "Screw" modifier and a "Weld" modifier afterwards if it has vertices exactly on the axis, therefore overlapping vertices.

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much. Would this be the same process if the end result was to bend the shape?

Comment: @Russ there's also a "Bend" modifier to bend a 3D shape.